# Change file names by Perl

Tags: regex, linux, perl, find

How to change file names from notation like this: `SomeCodeFile.extension` to C/C++ notation: `some_code_file.extension`. I'd like to use Perl + Find + Regex to print those names.

Comment: Did you tried anything from yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
perl -e 'for $f (@ARGV) {
             ($n = $f) =~ s/(?<=.)([[:upper:]])/_\l$1/g;
             rename $f, lcfirst $n;
         }' SomeCodeFiles*
```

- `[[:upper:]]` matches upper case letters.
- `(?<=.)` is a look behind assertion, i.e. the letter is preceded by something (we don't want `_some_code_file.ext`)
- `\l` changes the following letter to lowercase (similarly to `lcfirst`)

Note that the result might be unpleasant in some situations (`x_m_l2_j_s_o_n.c`, `u_r_l__validator.cpp`).

Comment: Could you match the upper case to lower case transition to avoid problems with e.g. XML. I think changing the 'look behind' to 'lower case character' would deal with that?

Comment: @Sobrique: It depends on what you expect. Just changing the `.` to `[[:lower:]]` doesn't seem right, though. Maybe changing `lcfirst` to `lc` at the same time...

Comment: Well, it does make: `camelCaseFile -> camel_case_file   and XML2JSON_parser -> XML2JSON_parser` - but you'd still have to worry about `lcfirst`ing that second case.